# Can't connect to D1 Mini with Micropython after running a program

Tags: esp32, micropython, thonny

I'm using D1 Mini with micropython
It happens a lot that I upload some code that has a main loop in it, and afterwards I lose connection to the board
I can see the console output, but can't see the files, can't burn a new firmware, can't stop the code from running, anything...

If I press ctrl+c or ctrl+d it holds for a second, then continues

I'm using a raspberry pi and Thonny for the development

Same from esptool and ampy

Tried looking for an answer online, but couldn't find anything relevant

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

What I do in my apps- I add time.sleep(3) at the beginning of my application. And when I wish to do code upload, I connect to the board, press CTRL+D for soft reset and CTRL+C to kill code. Then do upload required code. This approach works best for me.

Comment: Where do you do ctrl+d -> ctrl+c from? what are you using?

Comment: VSCode+Pymakr extension or Thonny, sometimes Putty

Comment: I tried that on a different D1 mini, now I have 2 devices which don't communicate

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen with ESP32 by the way

Answer (score 0):

Moved from pi to windows, I was able to delete and write the firmware again using esptool

The only thing is that now I have to press the reset button while connecting the USB so the computer will recognize the controller